# try if input is an int or a specific string

Tags: python, try-catch

I have a program that check if user input is an int. But I would also like to enable the user to write a specific string to exit the program, for example 'exit'.

What is a good solution to this problem. I want the try block to accept both an int or the string 'exit'.

```
try:
    inp = int(input('Int: '))

except ValueError:
    print('Not an int.')
```

Comment: Get a string from input. Check if it is 'exit'. If it's not, then try and convert it to an int.

Comment: So it's not an option to handle that inside the try block?

Comment: You're discarding the original input here if it doesn't convert to an `int`, so no, you can't check that again afterwards without storing it in a variable first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` cannot handle letters. One solution is to convert it to an integer after you input.

For example in this program, it first checks if `inp` is `'exit'`. If not, converts it to an integer.

```
try:
    inp = input('Int: ')
    if inp.lower()=='exit':
        print("Exit is entered")
    else:
        inp=int(inp)
except ValueError:
    print('Not an int.')
```

Or according to @Deceze's suggestion, you can narrow down the `try...except` around `int`

```
inp = input('Int: ')
if inp.lower()=='exit':
    print("Exit is entered")
else:
    try:
        inp=int(inp)
    except ValueError:
        print('Not an int.')
```